# How to write a property array inside a dictonary

Tags: objective-c

I am in need to enter the array inside a property value how to do it??

I have tried to add the array inside dictonary explicitly

```
NSDictionary *uilabeldropdown = @{ 
    @"UILabelDropDownWithTextField" : @{                                              
        @"headingLabel" : @{                                                      
            @"localizationKey" : @"Number"                                                      
        },
        @"userTextField" : @{                                                     
            @"xpath" : @"Home"                                                      
        },
        @"contentArray" : @[                                                     
            @"item 0":@"Home",                                                      
            @"item 1":@"New",                                                      
            @"item 2":@"ground"                                                      
        ]
    }
};
```

Comment: can you please elaborate the question?

Comment: You have non mutable objects. Could you show the expected result? And what you've tried? With what error?

Comment: `@"item 0":@"Home"` looks like a dictionary and must be between `@{}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@[...]` is the syntax for an `NSArray`, which does not support string keys.

```
@"contentArray" : @[                                                     
    @"item 0":@"Home",                                                      
    @"item 1":@"New",                                                      
    @"item 2":@"ground"                                                      
]
```

Remove the keys and access the values by index.

```
@"contentArray" : @[
    @"Home",
    @"New",
    @"ground"
]

uilabeldropdown[@"contentArray"][0]
```